# Returning Key:Val pair from Object Array

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a dictionary of properties from an object array using arrow functions. So far I've tried a few variations of this:

```
let scVars = {};
scVars = sheetNamedRanges.map(x => (
  {
    {x.getName()}: {x.getRange().getValue()}
  }
));
```

But I'm getting errors. I know this is a formatting issue but I'm a bit stuck so any help would be great

Comment: What is `sheetNamedRanges`, could you provide more details and more complete code?

Comment: `sheetNamedRanges` is the object array returned by `getNamedRanges` for a given spreadsheet. Thats definitely returning correctly because the functions `getName` and `getRange().getValue()` work fine outside the arrow function

Comment: Using a variable as key requires square brackets: `[x.getName()]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Array.map` will return another Array but what you probably want is to create a new object. Try it like this:

```js
let scVars = {};
sheetNamedRanges.forEach(x => {
    scVars[x.getName()] = x.getValue()
});
```

Comment: Thanks @llijaz. That does indeed work although just for anyone else you do need `x.getRange().getValue()` or you get a function error.